# Export all email addresses from a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a very basic question but I'm very new to JS and MongoDB and I can't find the solution anywhere nor anything I tried worked so far.

I have a Mongo DB with users in a DigitalOcean droplet, normally I access it through Robo 3T (Robomongo). All I want is a way to export all the email addresses from my users in a format I could use late (CSV, JSON...).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to JS world!

### Use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

[Here](https://www.quackit.com/mongodb/tutorial/mongodb_export_data.cfm) is a simple way to solve your problem, you can export to which ever formatted file you want csv or json.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Hey! This looks very good but (excuse my ignorance) this creates the file in the droplet, how can I just download it to my local machine?

Comment: after creating it on the droplet, you can easily access your server through any ftp application (i.e. FileZilla) and download it to your local machine